# Chrome Extension Installation Silently

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a installer for a chrome extension which will install silently.

At this time I made an installer but it needs a confirmation to enable it.

```
$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\${EXT_ID}\${PRODUCT_VERSION}_0
```

Copied my extension in this directory

```
Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\${EXT_ID}" "path" "${INSTALL_DIR}\${CRXNAME}
```

Registered in windows, but it needs confirmation to enable.

Is there any way I can do it silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Chrome 25 it is no longer possible to install extensions silently. Even when installed from outside of Chrome an extension will still require a confirmation.

Some resources related to this issue:

http://blog.chromium.org/2012/12/no-more-silent-extension-installs.html
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172608
http://www.infoworld.com/d/applications/chrome-25-will-disable-silently-installed-extensions-209780

Having said that, if you do find a way to install an extension silently without confirmation, please report it as a bug to the chromium team :)

Comment: I already read this. But I saw a installer done it silently. Thatsy Asked .